# javascript rock paper scissors score resetting every after one move

Tags: javascript, html

it's me, back at it again with my beginner problems and questions.
I'm trying to make a rock, paper, and scissors game with javascript and I think it's going pretty well but I'm currently stuck at the score keeping.. Everytime, after I choose a move, it'll log whether or not I'd won, and its also supposed to log the scores, but it always goes back down to zero, I tried some while loops(maybe I'm just using them in the wrong places?) but so far, none of my solutions worked, so yep, how do I fix this?

Thank you!

my javascript:

```
document.getElementById("Rock").onclick = function() {
    window.playerMove = "Rock";
    game();
}

document.getElementById("Paper").onclick = function() {
    window.playerMove = "Paper";
    game();
}

document.getElementById("Scissors").onclick = function() {
    window.playerMove = "Scissors";
    game();
}

function game() {
    window.playerScore = 0;
    window.computerScore = 0;

    var computerMoves = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
    var computerMove = computerMoves[Math.floor(Math.random()*computerMoves.length)];

    console.log(playerMove);
    console.log(computerMove);
    
    if (
    playerMove == "Rock" && computerMove == "Paper" || 
    playerMove == "Paper" && computerMove == "Scissors" || 
    playerMove == "Scissors" && computerMove == "Rock"
    ) {
        console.log("YOU WIN!!!");
        window.playerScore += 1;
    } 
    
    else if (
    computerMove == "Rock" && playerMove == "Paper" ||
    computerMove == "Paper" && playerMove == "Scissors" || 
    computerMove == "Scissors" && playerMove == "Rock") {
        console.log("YOU LOSE!!!");
        window.computerScore += 1 ;
    } 
    
    else if (playerMove == computerMove) {
        console.log("DRAW!!!");
    }
    document.getElementById("playerScore").innerHTML = window.playerScore;
    document.getElementById("computerScore").innerHTML = window.computerScore;
}
```

my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <!-- Custom Font For HeaderText -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>RPS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Title Container -->
    <div class="header-container">
        <div class="rainbowText"><h1><a href="https://github.com/Titsnium/rps">RPS</a></h1></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Buttons (Rock, Paper, Scissors)-->
    <div class="button-container">
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="button Rock" id="Rock"></button>
            <button class="button Paper" id="Paper"></button>
            <button class="button Scissors" id="Scissors"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Scoreboard -->
    <div class="board-container">
        <div class="playerBoard">
            <h1 id="playerScore">PLAYER: 0</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="versus">
            <h1>VS</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="computerBoard">
            <h1 id="computerScore">COMPUTER: 0</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Computer buttons I guess -->
    <div class="button-container">
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="button Rock"></button>
            <button class="button Paper"></button>
            <button class="button Scissors"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Result Container -->
    <div class="result-container">
        <div class="result">
            <h1>YOU WIN!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-container"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: At the very start of your game function, you set the score to zero. That means every time game() is run, the score will reset.

Comment: you reset the score everytime you call game() (`window.playerScore=0`), you need to for example have some sort of initialization function which sets them at zero in the beginning and then call some function which does not set the score back to zero but does the game logic

Comment: ong I get stuck on the most basic problems, all I had to do was move the variables outside the function?? *dies*

Answer (score 0):

Now the code is this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <!-- Custom Font For HeaderText -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>RPS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Title Container -->
    <div class="header-container">
        <div class="rainbowText"><h1><a href="https://github.com/Titsnium/rps">RPS</a></h1></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Buttons (Rock, Paper, Scissors)-->
    <div class="button-container">
        <div class="buttons">
            <input type="button" value="Rock" class="button Rock" id="Rock"></input>
            <input type="button" value="Paper" class="button Paper" id="Paper"></input>
            <input type="button" value="Scissors" class="button Scissors" id="Scissors"></input>
            <input type="button" value="Reset" class="button Reset" id="Reset"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Scoreboard -->
    <div class="board-container">
        <div class="playerBoard">
            <h1 id="playerScore">PLAYER: 0</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="versus">
            <h1>VS</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="computerBoard">
            <h1 id="computerScore">COMPUTER: 0</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Result Container -->
    <div class="result-container">
        <div class="result">
            <h1></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-container"></div>
    <script>
    window.playerScore = 0;
    window.computerScore = 0;
    </script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
document.getElementById("Rock").onclick = function() {
    window.playerMove = "Rock";
    game();
}

document.getElementById("Paper").onclick = function() {
    window.playerMove = "Paper";
    game();
}

document.getElementById("Scissors").onclick = function() {
    window.playerMove = "Scissors";
    game();
}

document.getElementById("Reset").onclick = function() {
    window.playerScore = 0;
    window.computerScore = 0;
    document.getElementById("playerScore").innerHTML = "PLAYER: 0";
    document.getElementById("computerScore").innerHTML = "COMPUTER: 0";
    document.querySelector("div.result h1").innerHTML = "";
}

function game() {

    var computerMoves = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
    var computerMove = computerMoves[Math.floor(Math.random()*computerMoves.length)];

    console.log(playerMove);
    console.log(computerMove);
    var state = "";
    
    if (
    playerMove == "Rock" && computerMove == "Paper" || 
    playerMove == "Paper" && computerMove == "Scissors" || 
    playerMove == "Scissors" && computerMove == "Rock"
    ) {
        console.log("YOU WIN!!!");
        state = "YOU WIN!!!";
        window.playerScore += 1;
    } 
    
    else if (
    computerMove == "Rock" && playerMove == "Paper" ||
    computerMove == "Paper" && playerMove == "Scissors" || 
    computerMove == "Scissors" && playerMove == "Rock") {
        console.log("YOU LOSE!!!");
        state = "YOU LOSE!!!";
        window.computerScore += 1 ;
    } 
    
    else if (playerMove == computerMove) {
        console.log("DRAW!!!");
        state = "DRAW!!!";
    }
    document.getElementById("playerScore").innerHTML = "PLAYER: " + window.playerScore;
    document.getElementById("computerScore").innerHTML = "COMPUTER: " + window.computerScore;
    document.querySelector("div.result h1").innerHTML = state;
}
```

## ***Look at the below CAREFULLY***

What I changed:

html:

```html
<!--Group 1-->
- <button class="button Rock" id="Rock"></button>
+ <input type="button" value="Rock" class="button Rock" id="Rock"></input>
- <button class="button Paper" id="Paper"></button>
+ <input type="button" value="Paper" class="button Paper" id="Paper"></input>
- <button class="button Scissors" id="Scissors"></button>
+ <input type="button" value="Scissors" class="button Scissors" id="Scissors"></input>
+ <input type="button" value="Reset" class="button Reset" id="Reset"></input>
<!--Group 2-->
- <!-- Computer buttons I guess -->
- <div class="button-container">
-     <div class="buttons">
-         <button class="button Rock"></button>
-         <button class="button Paper"></button>
-         <button class="button Scissors"></button>
-     </div>
- </div>
- <h1>YOU WIN!</h1>
+ <h1></h1>
<!--Group 3-->
+ <script>
+ window.playerScore = 0;
+ window.computerScore = 0;
+ </script>
```

js:

```js
// Group 4
+ document.getElementById("Reset").onclick = function() {
+     window.playerScore = 0;
+     window.computerScore = 0;
+     document.getElementById("playerScore").innerHTML = "PLAYER: 0";
+     document.getElementById("computerScore").innerHTML = "COMPUTER: 0";
+     document.querySelector("div.result h1").innerHTML = "";
+ }
// Group 5
+ var state = "";
+ state = "YOU WIN!!!"; // after console.log("YOU WIN!!!");
+ state = "YOU LOSE!!!"; // after console.log("YOU LOSE!!!");
+ state = "DRAW!!!"; // after console.log("DRAW!!!");
+ document.getElementById("playerScore").innerHTML = "PLAYER: " + window.playerScore;
+ document.getElementById("computerScore").innerHTML = "COMPUTER: " + window.computerScore;
+ document.querySelector("div.result h1").innerHTML = state;
```

### Group 1

`<button>` is not recommended in HTML5.
IE submits the text between `<button>` and `</button>`; other explorers submit the `value` attribute.

Use `<input type="button">` and **REMEMBER** to set the `value` attribute.

I added a reset button too.

### Group 2

Computer buttons are **Not necessary**

The state defaults to empty.

### Group 3

Reset the score when loaded.

### Group 4

Reset the score when clicked on the reset button.

### Group 5

Change the scores and the state when game changed.

### Now the game cam be played properly

Feel free to play it online at [my site](https://www.openwld.com/so_answers/rps/RPS.html)